# Conditions based on dynamic column names in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a following data:

```
name | product1_flag1 | product1_flag2 | product1_flag3 | product2_flag1 | product2_flag2 | product2_flag3
lmn  |              0 |              1 |              0 |              1 |              0 |              1
```

Here, Product names and number of products are dynamic. I want to create new column Product1_Final_Flag based on multiple flag values for each name like `if((flag1=1 or flag=0) and flag3=1) then "1" else "0"`.

Expected output as flows;

```
name | Product1_final_Flag | Product2_final_Flag
lmn  |                   0 |                   1
```

How should I achieve the same?

Comment: Do you have several products with names, all with the same flags, and you want to "test" the for all products ?? Am I getting the question?

Comment: Check the updated question. I have added expected output.

Comment: I strongly urge you to use a [tidy](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html) data format.  A little effort now will save you considerable pain in the future.

Comment: This question is a pure R question and is not specifically related to RStudio. Please remove that tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using DF shown reproducibly in the Note at the end, convert to long form having columns name, product, flag and value.  Then convert to wide form having columns name, product, flag1, flag2 and flag3.  Compute flag, append "_final_flag" to the product and select desired columns. Finally use pivot_wider to produce products along the top.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

DF %>%
  pivot_longer(-1, names_to = c("product", "flag"), names_sep = "_") %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = "flag") %>%
  mutate(flag = (flag1 | !flag2) * flag3,
         product = paste0(product, "_final_flag")) %>%
  select(name, product, flag) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = "product", values_from = "flag")
## # A tibble: 1 x 3
##   name  product1_final_flag product2_final_flag
##   <chr>               <int>               <int>
## 1 lmn                     0                   1
```

### Note

DF is shown in a reproducible manner here:

```
DF <- structure(list(name = "lmn", product1_flag1 = 0L, product1_flag2 = 1L, 
    product1_flag3 = 0L, product2_flag1 = 1L, product2_flag2 = 0L, 
    product2_flag3 = 1L), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -1L))
```